# Append "Version" of comments into cell

Tags: vba, excel

If the user enters a new comment, it is appended, but before the comment there should be some way we can convey to the user that you modified it. What I propose is the following

not approved.                        (This is initial content of the cell)
Version 1 : approved.            (This + above comment is content of the cell after first edit)
Version 2: subject to certain conditions. (This + the two comments above is content of the cell after second edit).

Please help me with this logic as I am on a tight deadline ! :( . I am very sure what I have below is pretty bad

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = NRemark
Else
    For i = 1 To 5
       ActiveCell.Value = "Version" & i & ":" & ActiveCell.Value & vbNewLine & "Version"   & i + 1 &  ":" & NRemark
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: Speaking of comments, have you considered putting all previous versions into a [cell comment](http://www.contextures.com/xlcomments01.html)? This would work somewhat like a cheap version of Word's `Track Changes` command.

Comment: yes, But this is for a master sheet that will consolidate all other required sheets. and sort of give feedback on certain comments. I am not sure if i am making sense but in short this sheet is just to give inputs and track the number of times the feedback is given

Comment: try creating "User Stories" for this concept.  Describe what needs to happen one step at a time and write it down.  Then look over the steps and the mistake should be clear.  I'm not exactly sure of what you are trying to have happen.  I am THINKING you are mistaken about iterating i from 1 to 5.  I think you just need to append the cell with the NEWEST comment.  To do that you'll have to find out what the LAST comment version was perhaps.  Again, not sure what you are doing.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right about the mistake and finding the newest comment. I will keep the user story concept in mind when i post a question

Comment: I don't mean you need to do that for posting a question.  Simply that doing that right now might help you see what needs to happen here.   If you started each line with Version1 or something, you could examine the cell's string and look at the position where the version number is kept.  Convert that to an Integer then add 1 to it, and insert that back into the new line..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: (Creates initial remark as version 1.  Adds a new remark at end with version = to the previous version plus 1.  It find the previous version by searching all characters in the string backwards until it finds a number.  THIS ONLY WORKS IF YOUR COMMENTS DO NOT CONTAIN NUMBERS!  OTHERWISE YOU WILL HAVE TO USE MY OTHER CODE BELOW!)

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = "Version 1: " & NRemark
Else
    If ActiveCell.Find("Version", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart) is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "Version 1: " & ActiveCell.Value
    Else
    End If
    For i = Len(ActiveCell.Value) to 1 Step -1
        currentChar = Mid(ActiveCell.Value, i, 1)
        If isnumeric(currentChar) = True Then Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next i
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & vbNewLine & "Version" & CInt(currentChar) + 1 & ": ", & NRemark 
    ActiveCell.WrapText = True
End If
```

If your comments include numeric characters then: (Puts the new version at the beginning so the search for current version number works if you have numeric characters later in the comments)

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = "Version 1: " & NRemark
Else
    If ActiveCell.Find("Version", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart) is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "Version 1: " & ActiveCell.Value
    Else
    End If
    For i = 1 To Len(ActiveCell.Value)
        currentChar = Mid(ActiveCell.Value, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(currentChar) = True Then Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next i
    ActiveCell.Value = "Version" & CInt(currentChar) + 1 & ": " & NRemark & vbNewLine & ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.WrapText = True
End If
```

Comment: hey Chrismas007 . Where do we end the First IF block ? I am getting an error . I tried ending it before " If isnumeric(currentChar) = True Then Exit For" but i still get an error

Comment: I added the "Exit For" in the next line . but i get an error at Next . btw i am talking about the second version of your code

Comment: Alright I have updated my code (in both examples).  Should work now.

Comment: thank you for the change . The code works for cases when either cell is blank or already consists an existing "Version" string. How do you advise the cases where there is an existing comment for which we can append "Version 1" or start the next appended comment with "Version 2" .